# замена ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal

Tags: android, kotlin

Реализовываю смену темы динамически, но необходимый метод `createCircularReveal` доступен только с API 21. Не можете посоветовать что-нибудь для более ранних версий?

```
val anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(imageView, w / 2, h / 2, finalRadius, 0f)
        anim.duration = 400L
        anim.doOnEnd {
            imageView.setImageDrawable(null)
            imageView.isVisible = false
        }
        anim.start()
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/circularreveal/CircularRevealCompat

Comment: @IR42 а есть пример использования, а то я смотрю конструктор требует не ConstraintLayout, а виджет CircularRevealWidget, который мне придется заменять на всех Layout?

Comment: виноват, увидел Compat, но не посмотрел, что там не такие же параметры как и у createCircularReveal

Comment: [тыц](https://habr.com/ru/post/243541/)

Comment: @Circassian уже видел, один фиг он там свой Custom Layout использует